# How to resolve multiple open duplicates of essentially the same question

Tags: discussion, duplicates, vote-to-close

There are 4 variations of essentially the same question about the effect of pressure on dew point. From oldest to newest they are:

1. [How does athmospheric pressure influence dewpoint?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/777960/145491)
2. [To calculate the dewpoint ºC increase in a compressed air line](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/542687/145491)
3. [How does atmospheric pressure affect dew point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466141/145491)
4. [What law or formula discusses the relationship between pressure and dew point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371175/145491)

I nominated the the newest one for closure, and was thinking of nominating two more, but am confused about which one to keep.

- Question 2 has the most understandable [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/542868/145491) in my opinion, but needs links and a bit more physics details.
- Question 3 has clearest title and the most views.
- Question 4 is the oldest question with the most answers, but they are not all that clear in my opinion.

If no one else does it, I might eventually be tempted to write (what I hope is) a clear canonical answer with cross-references to the helpful answers in the various questions, but wouldn't know which question to attach it to.

Should 3 of the 4 be closed as duplicates, and if so, which 3?